# change lux value in a press of a button

Tags: android, sensors

I just started Android studio yesterday. Im trying to convert the lux value of the light sensor with the use of a button. I have created a button, i want to know how to change the value. The equation should be: lux value multiply by 0.002? I want to know the java code. Light sensor is already working. just want to change the value with the said equation.. tried searching for continues equation but having difficulty. hoping for an answer. thank you.

```
TextView textView;

SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        textView.setText("" + sensorEvent.values[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Attach your button code here.

Comment: @SandeepInsan    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/blue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

Comment: where you handling the click of this button in code ?

Comment: @SandeepInsan the button id is working fine but the code is my problem: textView.setText(String.valueOf(textView.getText().toString()*0.002));

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here in getting the text from "textView".
you are getting String value and trying to multiply string with float.

You have to do it like this:

```
    String value = textView.getText().toString().trim();
    textView.setText(String.valueOf((Float.parseFloat(value))*0.02));
```

Here "value" is a String and first you have to parse it to Float before multiplying.

Try to do like above code.